# How can I insert data into a table that has a composite primary key through JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, insert, composite-primary-key

User Table

UserName pk
fname
lname

GroupMaster

GroupName pk
UserName pk, fk

I want to insert data in GroupMaster but my problem is it has composite primary key

How can I insert data in table through entity manager object?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the `@Embeddable` annotation. Set up a new class that contains the values of the primary key -- in this case, a class with `GroupName` and `UserName` fields, annotate the class with `@Embeddable`, then store an instance inside the `@Entity` that requires the primary key.

Take a look at the following example:

[Using composite keys in Hibernate](http://java-aap.blogspot.com/2006/04/hibernate-annotations-composite.html)

Comment: I already have class but i want the exact way to insert data like em.persist(whichobject)

Comment: @user1904230 - There should be two classes -- one is your `@Entity`, one is your `@Embeddable`. You would persist the `@Entity`.